# Why can't I convert signed int to unsigned long

Tags: java, io, binary, hex

I'm reading numeric data from a file in Java:

Data of one byte length represents an `unsigned byte`
Data of two bytes length represents an `unsigned short`
Data of four bytes length represents an `unsigned int`

But because Java 7 doesn't have unsigned types, I need to use a `short`/`integer` to represent the whole range of byte values, an `integer` to represent a short value and I assume a `long` to represent an integer value.

But I'm having problems with representing the integer values

I have these three methods:

```
 public class Utils 
 { 
    public static int u(short n)
    {
        return n & 0xffff;
    }


    public static int u(byte n)
    {
        return n & 0xff;
    }

     public static long u(int n)
    {
        return n & 0xffffffff;
    }
}
```

and three test cases, but only the first two test cases work:

```
public void testByteToUnsignedIntConversion()
    {
        byte maxByte = (byte)0xff;
        int  maxNotConverted = maxByte;
        int  maxConverted    = Utils.u(maxByte);
        System.out.println(maxConverted + ":" + maxNotConverted);
        assertEquals(255,maxConverted);
    }

    public void testShortToUnsignedIntConversion()
    {
        short maxShort = (short)0xffff;
        int  maxNotConverted = maxShort;
        int  maxConverted    = Utils.u(maxShort);
        System.out.println(maxConverted + ":" + maxNotConverted);
        assertEquals(65535,maxConverted);
    }

    public void testIntToUnsignedLongConversion()
    {
        int maxInt = 0xffffffff;
        long  maxNotConverted = maxInt;
        long  maxConverted    = Utils.u(maxInt);
        System.out.println(maxConverted + ":" + maxNotConverted);
        assertEquals(4294967296l,maxConverted);
    }
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: To begin with, do you understand the point of those `& 0xfff...fff` things? I think your misunderstanding begins there.

Comment: Anyway, fix it like this: `return (long) n & 0xffffffff;`.

Comment: Or just make the constant a long: `n & 0xffffffffL`

Comment: Ah does n implicity become an integer in all those methods and then 0xff masks out al but the lowest byte , 0xff0xff masks all but lowest two bytes , and it fails for the last one because I need to make long before masking, but your right Marko I dont quite get it

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik your fix didnt work for me,

Comment: but @JonSkeet yours did

Comment: Yes, there's  a subtle problem with my version: the bitmask itself gets sign-extended to `0xffffffffffffffff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitwise and (&) deals with operands as integers unless you state otherwise. that's why it worked with byte and short since the methods return an integer. so since you want the result to be a long value to deal with it as unsigned value, you should and with the integer max value mask (i.e. 2^32-1 or 0xFFFFFFFF) and cast it long. Long constants should end with L in java, so just modify it to the following:

```
public static long u(int n)
{
    return n & 0xffffffffL;
}
```

if what you you need is make arithmetic operations on the unsigned values and it doesn't matter which version of java you use, I would suggest to use java 8 since it has methods in Long, Integer, Byte and Short classes to do such unsigned operations.

Comment: 'Bitwise and (&) deals with operands as integers ' - that was the key part I didn't understand, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than rolling your own, Guava has got helper methods for unsigned values -  [`UnsignedInts`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html), [`UnsignedLongs`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLongs.html) etc (for more information, see [their wiki](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PrimitivesExplained#Unsigned_support)), and there's built-in methods in Java 8 to use as well - [`parseUnsignedInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-), [`divideUnsigned`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#divideUnsigned-int-int-) etc

Comment: Thanks, but for now as this is a public lib i cant move to Java 8 and I dont want to add the guava dependency, hopefully will in the future